# Datadog java agent and GraalVM native executable

Tags: java, spring-boot, datadog, graalvm-native-image

I use spring boot 3.1.x and I prepared a native images with Spring Boot GraalVM tooling. Previously with using fat jar we passed datadog java agent to application to add tracing like that:

```
java -javaagent:/usr/src/app/dd-java-agent.jar -jar app-fat-jar.jar
```

After compiling a native image I tried to pass it to the executable in the same manner:

```
/cnb/process/web -javaagent:/workspace/dd-java-agent.jar
```

But it seems not to have any effect on running native image. So the datadog traces don't get exported to datadog at all.

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: [This issue](https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1065) seems relevant